# Pygame, how to remove trail from a player when moving, I tried filling screen but still didnt work for me

Tags: python, pygame

So I am trying to remove the trail from player while it moves. I tried to do screen.fill, but when I do it, then the whole map disappears. I want to achieve a simple moving ascii letter. - tiles(map1) is supposed to draw the map, however if I put screen.fill before it, then the map will disappear i have no idea why.

```
import pygame
from pygame import key
from pygame.draw import rect
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

resmulti=3
spritesize=16*resmulti
resolution=(256*resmulti,224*resmulti)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((resolution[0], resolution[1]))

pygame.display.set_caption("test")

player_character = "@"
player_color = (255, 0, 0)
player_size = 20
current_position = [0, 1]

player = pygame.font.Font(None, player_size).render(player_character,False, player_color)
tile = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), [0,0,10,10])


map1 = """

wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
w                                w
w      wwwww      w   ww         w
w                     w          w
w        w                       w
w                www      www    w
w            w    w       w      w
w      w          w       w      w
w      w      wwwww      www     w
w                                w
wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
"""
map1 = map1.splitlines()

gameRunning = True

background = pygame.image.load("bg.png")

def tiles(map1):
    global tile
    for y,line in enumerate(map1):
        for x,c in enumerate(line):
            if c == "w":
                screen.blit(screen,(x*16,y*16),tile)


p_x = 20
p_y = 90
while gameRunning:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameRunning = False
            break
        
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[K_DOWN]:
        p_y += 2
    elif keys[K_UP]:
        p_y = p_y - 2
    elif keys[K_LEFT]:
        p_x = p_x - 2
    elif keys[K_RIGHT]:
        p_x += 2


    tiles(map1)

    screen.blit(player,(p_x,p_y))

    fpsClock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: filling the screen should be done before drawing anything else

Comment: @Matiiss for some reason it doesnt help, I did: 
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    screen.blit(player,(p_x,p_y))
    tiles(map1)
    pygame.display.flip()

I think because the map will be under the filled screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tile = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), [0,0,10,10])
```

That returns a pygame.Rect object, so tile is a rect.

Then you use tile in the blit function.

```
screen.blit(screen,(x*16,y*16),tile)
```

But from pygame's documentation, blit takes a pygame.Surface not a rect.

To fix the problem.

Make tile a pygame.Surface.

```
#tile = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), [0,0,10,10])
tile = pygame.Surface((10, 10)).convert()
tile.fill((255, 255, 255))
```

Draw the tile as follows.

```
if c == "w":
     screen.blit(tile,(x*16,y*16))
```

Then clear screen, draw tiles, draw player.

```
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
tiles(map1)
screen.blit(player,(p_x,p_y))
```

Comment: the reason is not correct but the solution seems to work

Comment: @Matiiss How is the reason not correct? pygame's documentation shows blits's signature as `blit(source, dest, area=None, special_flags=0)`. source being the source surface, in this case tile. dest being the position to blit. His arguments were of right types, so no error but was being interpreted wrong.

Comment: yes, of course, they provided `screen` as the source which is a surface and they also provided the area to use from that surface which was a rectangle because `draw` returns a rectangle, so basically they were blitting that area of `screen` (which was colored in white using `draw`) in other places, meaning that if that area changed color, all of the tiles would change color too

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to simply replace

```py
screen.blit(screen, (x * 16, y * 16), tile)
```

with

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (x * 16, y * 16, 10, 10))
```

The issue you had was that you were `blit`ing an area of the `screen`, the same area that you had colored white previously (`tile = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), [0,0,10,10])`). The issue is that if you for example used `fill` to fill the `screen` with some color, it would also fill in that drawn square you had and it would no more be white but the filled color and since your tiles would be then created in that same color, they would be the same color as the entire `screen`. So you could either create a new surface (or use an image) or just use `draw` function as I have shown.

This allows then to use `blit` or `fill` at the start of the `while` loop to fill the screen with background color.